# Fixed Effects Regression Constant / Intercept Using FELM in R

Tags: r, regression, lfe

How does one obtain the intercept ('constant') when using the `felm` function (of the `lfe` package) for panel data with fixed effects?

Reproducible example:

```
library(lfe)
set.seed(42)
x <- rnorm(100000)
f1 <- sample(10000, length(x), replace=TRUE)
f2 <- sample(10000, length(x), replace=TRUE)
y <- 2.13*x + cos(f1) + log(f2+1) + rnorm(length(x), sd=0.5)
est <- felm(y ~ x + G(f1) + G(f2))
summary(est)
```

This yields:

```
Call:
felm(formula = y ~ x + G(f1) + G(f2))

Residuals

Min 1Q Median 3Q Max
-1.9531308 -0.3018539 -0.0003573 0.3007738 2.2052754

Coefficients:
Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
x 2.130889 0.001768 1205 <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes: 0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
Residual standard error: 0.5013 on 80000 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared: 0.9683 Adjusted R-squared: 0.9603
F-statistic: 122.1 on 19999 and 80000 DF, p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Notice there is no intercept...

I noticed the following in the 'lfe' package documentation (https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2013/RJ-2013-031/RJ-2013-031.pdf):

*"The careful reader has noticed that the behaviour of summary() on a ’felm’ object with respect to degrees of freedom and R 2 is the same as that of on an ’lm’ object when including an intercept. There is no explicit intercept in the result of felm(), but the factor structure includes one implicitly"*

Thank you.

Comment: The random variables in mixed models are usually categorical. I wouldn't know what it meant to talk about an intercept in the context you create.